# Loadrunner: Capturing the response times of document downloads?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I have a Loadrunner script, and I want to capture the response times of 3 document files that I download through the web-application. In my current recording, these documents are shown as "Extrares" and therefore their response times are not being calculated individually.

Here's the pertinent part of the recording (I've used vague domains/paths to not risk any ability to identify the customer/application):

```
web_url("2367_5", 
    "URL=https://web-application-domain/", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", 
    "Referer=https://web-application-domain/", 
    "Snapshot=t110.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    EXTRARES, 
    "Url=/Document/Document1/", "Referer=", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/Document/Document2/", "Referer=", ENDITEM, 
    "Url=/Document/Document3/", "Referer=", ENDITEM, 
    LAST);
```

I want the response times of Document 1, Document 2, and Document 3, as separate transactions.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on time-taken in your HTTP logs and then parse the logs after your test for this data.

Comment: I'm not seeing this option ("time taken"). Can you help point me to it? I use Loadrunner 12.55. I discovered your Podcast by the way. I've been going through the episodes. Seems like it will be very useful as an educational tool.

Comment: Take a look at your web server configuration for logs.  Every web server which claims w3c compliance has to support their standard log options, which includes the time-taken data field.  Every web server and web application server (Apache, IIS, nginx, tomcat, jboss, weblogic, ...) all support this logging option.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the extrares from the first url call and make 3 separate calls one for each document after that:

```
web_url("Document1", 
    "URL=https://web-application-domain/Document/Document1/", //put the correct path here
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", // edit according to the content type of the doc
    "Referer=https://web-application-domain/",  // probably useless, just comment it
    "Snapshot=t110.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    LAST);
```